# Creating a knowledge base with common relational databases

Tags: relational-database, recommendation-engine, expert-system, knowledge-management

It might be silly question and i know for such systems they usually use Ontology authoring tools or Rule-based languages like CLIPS, but is it possible to create a Knowledge base by relational databases?

For example, let's say i want to create a recommendation system for diabetes patients.The application gets their blood glucose level and response a recommendation based on their health situation. (I guess this one could be easily implemented by a mapping table )

But what if other factors like Age, Male/Female,calorie intake etc add to the problem.

Is it still possible to design a knowledge base in which has the relation of these factors and a recommendation table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do that,but it's not recommended. It has a very high overhead on the system and it may not probably be responsive.